# Ace Editor - How to pass event data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ace-editor

I have a function to expand/collapse the size of the ace editor, and this is triggered by a button.

I need to trigger the 'expand' once the editor gain focus. So I was doing something like this:

```
var editor = ace.edit("theeditor");
editor.on("focus", myFocusHandler);
```

And the `myFocusHandler` looks something like this:

```
var myFocusHandler = function(event) {
    // do some resize stuff here ...
    var toggleSizeButton = jQuery("expand-collapse-button");
    toggleSizeButton .toggleClass("glyphicon-resize-small");
    toggleSizeButton .toggleClass("glyphicon-resize-full");
}
```

So far so good. The problem started when I had to refactor my code to support multiple ace editors in the same web page. With jQuery I could use the `this` inside the event handler to get the current editor and then get the button relative to it using jQuery DOM traversing functions. How can I do that (or pass event data) into an event handler with Ace? I would like to do something like this:

```
var myFocusHandler = function(event) {
    // do some resize stuff here...
    var theEditorDiv = jQuery(this); // I know this is wrong
    var toggleSizeButton = theEditorDiv.prev("div.toggle-button").find(".glyphicon");
    toggleSizeButton.toggleClass("glyphicon-resize-small");
    toggleSizeButton.toggleClass("glyphicon-resize-full");
}
```

The call to `jQuery(this)` is wrong for two reasons: first, `this` is undefined, second, even if it was a valid reference to the editor, it is not a DOM element.

So, two questions here.

1. How to get a reference to the ace editor object inside the event handler
2. How to get the `div` element where the ace editor is built into.

Any ideias? Ace editor API documentation gives no clue about this.

Answer (score 0):

There is only experimental api for getting event target in event listener. You can do

```
var myFocusHandler = function(event, editor) {
    var theEditorDiv = jQuery(editor.container);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ace exposes the editor object as a second parameter on the events. You could do something like the below:

### HTML

```
<h2>Editor 1</h2>
<pre class="editor"></pre>

<h2>Editor 2</h2>
<pre class="editor"></pre>
```

### Javascript

```
$('.editor').each(function() {

    var editor = ace.edit(this);

    editor.on('focus', function(event, editor) {
         $(editor.container).animate({ width: 500 });
    });

    editor.on('blur', function(event, editor) {
        $(editor.container).animate({ width: 300 });
    });

});
```

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/2t5ruscx/2